# how to set open Launch Application via group policy for callTo protocol

Tags: group-policy, protocol

I have implemented callTo protocol to call a dialer and vbs script from web page within the intranet. I have deployed the registry to all machines in network via group policy and his all works fine. how ever on a new machine I get the dialog box "Launch Application".

What can I do to set this via group policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to include the following in the registry for ie

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\callto]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

Not sure about firefox as of yet